# Json Data table passing failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

My AJAX is not working but my JSON result is return row count is 12 and it is not showing any alert messages. I check in browser, it shows 500 internal server error.

If checking purpose I given string value is working for data table is not working there is any other method for getting data table

My JSON Result

```
public ActionResult GroupFix(string id, string name)
{
    List<Tbltable> Fix = new List<Tbltable>();
    Fix = entity.Tbltable.Where(x => x.Name == name && x.id == id).ToList();            
    return Json(Fix, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My jQuery

```
$.post("/Home/GroupFix", { name: Name, id : id }, function (result) {
           alert('hai');
           $.each(result, function (value, key) {
               alert('name');
               $('#fixtab tbody').append('<tr> <td>' + value.name + '</td> <td>' + value.id + '</td>  </tr>');
           });
       }, "json");
```

Comment: Can you show your JSON-formatted response instead of the code that created it?

Comment: Well, something's happening inside your server. It might as well be a data base server problem. Just try to debug it. First, make it return a static text and see if the browser connects to the action or not...

Comment: if i pass the string value is will be return but data table is not responding

Comment: See that post i m not getting answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not get exact problem, but see below code which work as I wish in my case...

Jquery

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "url",
       data: "jason-data",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(msg) {
              var t = window.JSON.parse(msg.d);
              // Your code.
        }
});
```

c# code

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SendMessage()
{
      // Code 
      // return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize();
}
```

Make sure jason key datatype and it's name same as the argument name of method called ba parameters....

Comment: its returning single value but i need to pass data table

Comment: You can pass datatable .. `return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new Hashtable { { "r", "Message sent successfully." } });` as the same I am doing
...

Comment: return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new Hashtable { { Fixture } }); its right its showing error no overload for method 'Add' take 1 argument

Comment: Try this. `return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Fixture );` I guess it helps u...

Comment: Cannot implict convert type 'string' to 'System.web.mvc.Actionresult' error is coming to this code return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Fixture );

Answer (score 1):

try to Use the ajax post as::

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    Url:"GroupFix",
    data:{id=2,name='TestName'},
    success:function(data){

       for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
             alert('name');
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Ya friend my ajax is working for display string one getting single row from the database but it not getting more than one row from the data base

Comment: then have a look in your controller's action code by using breakpoint that how many results you get from database.

Comment: Ya friend it can return 12 row count as a list but in my view is not showing any alert message also