# Json Data Table Passing Failure

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

My ajax is not working but my json result is return row count is 12 and it not show any alert message and i check in browser it shows 500 internal server error please some one help me friend

if checking purpose i given string value is working for data table is not working there is any other method for getting data table

My JSON Result

```
public ActionResult GroupFix(string id, string name)
{
    List<Tbltable> Fix = new List<Tbltable>();
    Fix = entity.Tbltable.Where(x => x.Name == name && x.id == id).ToList();            
    return Json(Fix, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My jquery

```
$.post("/Home/GroupFix", { name: Name, id : id }, function (result) {
           alert('hai');
           $.each(result, function (value, key) {
               alert('name');
               $('#fixtab tbody').append('<tr> <td>' + value.name + '</td> <td>' + value.id + '</td>  </tr>');
           });
       }, "json");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json Data table passing failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398100/json-data-table-passing-failed)